# Runtime Error Window fails to pop up in Flash Player 10.3.181.34 Debug

Tags: flash

I've installed the latest debug version of Flash player plugin for Mac OS X. Diagnostic page http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/865/cpsid_86551.html#ostype=m,prob1=fpver confirms that the version of Flash plugin detected is debugger one. I'am also able to debug applications using Flash-builder debugging tools. But no runtime error pop-ups are shown during browsing. Does anyone have the same problem? Does anyone know how to fix this strange behavior?

I've tried to uninstall the player using this application http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/uninstall_flash_player_osx.dmg and reinstall Flash player again, but no luck.

**UPD1:** I've created additional user account and found out that error pop-ups are displayed successfully when switched to that account. So it's likely user-profile configuration issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your [mm.cfg](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fc9.html).  Since you're on a mac, it would be in ~ or /Library/Application Support/Macromedia.  This key looks like it might cause that behavior: SuppressDebuggerExceptionDialogs=1

Comment: Thank you Sean! I've changed this key value to 0 and that enabled pop-up messages.

Comment: Perfect article for digging in mm.cfg [http://jpauclair.net/mm-cfg-secrets/](http://jpauclair.net/mm-cfg-secrets/)